# Objects and get_post_meta() gives me 1 string for latitude and longitude

Tags: ajax, geo-data

I am using Geo Data Store plugin and sending my post's lat/longs to AJAX.

Everything is available via return Object and working fine except the lat/long is in one string. This must be a common roadblock for this plugin?

My loop:

```
foreach ($q->posts as $post) {
        $array[$i] = array();
        $array[$i]['title'] = $post->post_title;
        $array[$i]['permalink'] = $post->post_name;
        $array[$i]['post_coords'] = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'loc_coords', true);
        //$array[$i]['post_coords'] = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'loc_coords', false);
    $i++;
}

    echo json_encode($array);
```

JS

```
for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
data = response[i];

// How to get lat/ long separated?
//$('#results').append(data.title + '<br />' + data.lat + data.lon); // someday
$('#results').append(data.title + '<br />' + data.lat + data.post_coords); 
}
```

get_post_meta() sends its value back as an array of 1 if set to false...

This would all have worked smoothly but LatLng seems to demand 2 arguments when Geo Data Store returns both lat/long as 1 string.

```
position: new google.maps.LatLng(data.post_coords)    // no good
position: new google.maps.LatLng(41.99990, -71.39923) // good
```

UPDATE:
The answer was from Milo with PHP's explode() to split up the string and assign latitude and longitude separately. Thanks for the help here.

```
$split = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'loc_coords', true); 
    $coords = explode(",", $split);
    $array[$i]['lat'] = $coords[0];
    $array[$i]['lon'] = $coords[1];
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I don't think this is a WordPress question, just php or javascript. search for php explode or javascript split.